# #1064 Error Creating Table in phpmyadmin in XAMPP involving datetime|timestamp

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, mysql-error-1064, create-table

I'm failing at creating a basic table in mySQL to track emails sent to an existing email list in the same db and folder, including (1) a serial number (2) timestamp when sent  (3) email subject (4) email body (5) source email.

This question varies from prior ones on your site (which I have read through at length) because it SO BASIC - I'm literally creating 3 basic field types and having an error so profound I cannot move forward.  All others I found have either more complex considerations / factors such as joins, migration, etc. where the error lay in user's understanding of those complex layers or partially understood or inherited code copied, or true novice ones where someone didn't understand the basic data type or basic syntax and a review of any beginning mySQL / SQL book would clear it up.  So none apply to this case:  a clean, simple beginner's level case with only settings and drop downs to choose (no syntax required by me!) where it won't work and creates, of all things, syntax errors!

I'm using using XAMPP for OS X 5.6.19-0 [2016-03-04], mySQL version is mariaDB and I'm working on a macbook air using OS X Mavericks.  I'm basing this example off of "HeadFirst PHP & MySQL" book chapter 3, where as always I attempt to extend the example to flex my muscles of understanding, only to hit a wall!

DB: 'elvis_store', table to create: 'emails_sent'.  My phpmyadmin screen looks like this (comma delimited and portrayed similarly to a nonnumeric array because columns were not respected in your formatting) - all unmentioned columns/ setting were left blank to default:

Name: email#; Type: INT; Index: INDEX; A_I: [✔︎](box checked); Virtuality: PERSISTENT.

Name: date-time_sent; Type: DATETIME; Virtuality: PERSISTENT;

Name: email_subject; Type: VARCHAR (75); Virtuality: PERSISTENT;

Name: email_body; Type: TEXT (65,535); Virtuality: PERSISTENT;

Name: sent_from_email; Type: VARCHAR (75); Virtuality: PERSISTENT;

ALL FIELDS: 
collation:       utf8_unicode_ci (each column/overall)
MIME type:       text / plain

Storage Engine:  InnoDB

phpmyadmin's translation to SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE `elvis_store`.`emails_sent` (
    `email` INT AS () PERSISTENT , 
    `date-time_sent` DATETIME AS () PERSISTENT ,
    `email_subject` VARCHAR(75) AS () PERSISTENT , 
    `email_body` TEXT AS () PERSISTENT , 
    `sent_from_email` VARCHAR(75) AS () PERSISTENT , 
    INDEX (`email`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I get a #1064 this error when I hit the "save" at bottom or "go" button at top:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')PERSISTENT , `date-time_sent` DATETIME AS () PERSISTENT , `email_subject` VA' at line 1"

Variations in error #1064 based on trying many options that could possibly make sense to me, ALWAYS mention the "TIMESTAMP" / "DATETIME" names, values, etc., so it's likely the problem.  Manipulating DATETIME values and time stamps are CENTRAL to the functionality of my web app so how to handle creating tables and columns with such values - the do's and don't's - are the focus of my question, esp since I think I have VARCHAR and the INT index working in another table and exercise in the same workbook.

I tried the following to no avail (still get #1064 error):

1. eliminating "#" and "-" from field names - I don't see that the collation I used prevents use of these special characters;
2. changing date-time_sent type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP and DATE;
3. changing default value of datetime/timestamp field be be null by default, and or allow null values (checking the check box), in various combinations;
4. varying (drastically reducing) size of text field to under 500 characters in case that's was problem with my version of XAMPP/ SQL / PHP

I don't see any degrees of freedom left how to change this because:

1. all fields need to be persistent - once an email is sent
2. emails must have an auto incremented serial number index,
3. automatic time stamp must be the default, created as emails go out;
4. Collation must be a form of utf for likely high volume of international customers;
5. I don't understand why the "AS ()" is added by phpmyadmin in creating the SQL equivalent of my check boxes and drop downs, but surely that wouldn't error if it's the system creating that language;
6. Timestamp must be DATETIME type because range '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31' is preferable to TIMESTAMP type's narrower range ('1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC). I don't want to go in planning on rewriting my site with all the time stamps being unsupported in 20 years from now (2018-2038) esp if these matters are central to my web app, if I don't have to anyway.

So I'm stuck.  Why the #1064 errors and how can I create this basic table?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

A virtual column, also called a computed or a generated column, is a column in a table that has its value automatically calculated using a deterministic expression, in particular from the values of other fields in the table.

Storage engines that support them are  InnoDB, Aria, MyISAM and CONNECT

Judging from your basic table and question, I understand you want to be able to add data on your own, when using my php admin table creation, you don't need input for all the columns in the structure, avoid **Default,Collation, Attributes,Index,Vituality, MIME type and Browser Transformation**; when creating a basic table, you can add the ones you need when you ALTER the table.

> all fields need to be persistent - once an email is sent

I don't understand what this line means, but the database row shouldn't change once you select data from it to send an email. That's not what the virtuality [column is about; read more here

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/

A working query for your table would be

```
CREATE TABLE `elvis_store`.`emails_sent` (
    `email` INT, 
    `date-time_sent` DATETIME,
    `email_subject` VARCHAR(75), 
    `email_body` TEXT, 
    `sent_from_email` VARCHAR(75) , 
    INDEX (`email`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I think I didn't understand virtuality - both "virtual" and "persistent" - refer to calculated columns vs. the blank, default, means that it's persistent anyway, just not calculated.  That explains my problem.  I removed the "Virtuality" specifiers and it worked.  Read my answer below for more comments and details, but this explains why.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hours after posting here, I thought perhaps the datetime value ("date-time_sent") was being tripped up by my specifying "persistent", because it's one of the only specifiers left to remove and was perhaps designed to default to persistence of some kind - why time-stamp something if you're not going to store that info? I realized this might be a pattern:  unnecessary specifiers can trip you up in mySQL table creation.

Once before I'd had a problem creating a table in the same mariaDB XAMPP setup where an extra specifier - in that case the auto-incremented INT index designated as "unsigned" (logical, right? since it should start at zero and go in the positive direction) caused error messages until removed. Apparently mySQL (in this case mariaDB) knows that indexes should start at zero so that redundant specifier not only wasn't needed, it error-blocked table creation.  Similarly in this case, mySQL knows to by default store and keep values persistently without specifying "persistent".

As mentioned in above comment response, I removed all "virtuality" specifiers starting with datetime ("date-time_sent") column thinking it unique, and errors moved around until all Virtuality specifiers were removed, and table was created.  As mentioned above, in this case I misunderstood that the default in Virtuality means a stored, persistent value just not calculated, so it wasn't redundant / unnecessary specifiers but rather misunderstanding specifiers (see response above).  However, I think there's a lesson in this when combined with that prior problem - added specifiers in mySQL table creation can be the source of otherwise unexplained errors, and that specifiers should be removed and mySQL defaults tested, even if the defaults seem to new developers like me to be necessary, because sometimes they're not.